# Do the days of forbidding non vegetarian food depends on the time of birth?

Tags: scripture, food

It is well known from scriptures that one should avoid non vegetarian foods on the festivals, special days such as Sunday, full moon, new moon etc.,

But other than those that are common to everyone, are there any special restrictions based solely on birth time?

Comment: Special restrictions shd be there because the astrological charts have "Ghatak" or malefic list. Some days/nakshtras/tithis/months are malefic for some natives but not so for others. So, if fasting or avoiding non-veg food is done as part of an astrological remedy, then yes. For e.g. if Sunday is in the Ghatak list for a particular person then it is usually good for him to fast on Sundays or have a restrictive diet on those days.